# Installed BeautifulSoup4 in both Python 2.7 and 3.6, but ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I've successfully installed BeautifulSoup4 in 2.7 and 3.6 in the terminal, but when I use either Spyder or Jupyter Notebook, I get the following error when trying to import bs4 when using the Python 3.6 kernel

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I've tried the following Terminal commands:

- sudo apt-get install python3-bs4
- python3.6 -m pip install bs4
- py3.6 -m pip install bs4
- sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
- python3.6 /Users/MY-NAME/anaconda/bin/pip install bs4

NB: I have created separate kernels for the two versions of python:

- py27
- py3.6

Any other solutions that I haven't tried or anything that I've obviously missed/misunderstood?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What about `pip3 install bs4`?

Comment: if i'm not mistaken the command should be `pip install beautifulsoup4`, at least that's what's in the docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was going wrong.
So for anyone else running into this problem, I had to do the following:

#### 1. Activate the environment

Activate the environment (i.e. the Kernel for the python version) by using the terminal command:

```
$ source activate NAME_OF_YOUR_KERNEL
```

For which I typed in:

```
$ source activate py3.6
```

#### 2. Install the target package

Install the target package using the terminal command:

```
$ conda install TARGET_PACKAGE_NAME
```

For which I typed in:

```
$ conda install beautifulsoup4
```

#### 3. Deactivate your environment

```
$ source deactivate NAME_OF_YOUR_KERNEL
```

For which I typed:

```
$ source deactivate py3.6
```